# How to reset an HTML5 canvas context to default values?

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I know if I start a canvas from scratch I can use `context.save()` before any changes and then use `context.restore()` later to recover it. My question is: **If I get a canvas that is already modified, before I could even use the `context.save()` command, how can I reset the whole context to default values?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite unfortunate, but actually you can't do it perfectly, because the clipping API is broken...

All other properties can be set to some absolute values: the obvious `fill/strokeStyle`, `font`, `shadowXXX` etc. Even the transformation matrix can be set absolutely to the identity matrix with either `resetTransform()` or `setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`.
The one thing we can not set absolutely is the clipping region. For this one, you must have an initial `save()`, (or to have [my `setClip` polyfill](https://github.com/Kaiido/canvas-setClip) installed).
Unfortunately, even though it has been requested many times, some implementers are trully against including a `setClip()` in the specs...

Thus the only way to reset the context completely without an initial call to `save()` is to reset the `width` or `height` properties of the `<canvas>` element. But doing so you will also clear any current drawing on the context, and you will kill your app's memory usage: at least in Chrome, a new drawing buffer is being assigned when you do so, meaning the GC has to kick in to collect the previous buffer which may be of consequent size with big canvases. In the future we should be able to call a [`reset()`](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/5618#issuecomment-642209330) method which should avoid this realloc problem, but it will still clear the drawing buffer anyway.